# Changing dataprovider of a datagrid on change event of another datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flexbuilder, flex4.5

I have two datagrids: 
 - Division
 - Members 
Both have single columns. Selecting one item from Divsions datagrid should display members of that Division in the Members datagrid. But following code has some problem and Members of a particular division do not show up when respective Divsion is clicked.

Following are some snippets of the related code. Hope someone can spot an error in it.

```
private var divs_array:Array = ['Division A','Division B'];
[Bindable] private var divisions:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(divs_array);

private var memA_array:Array = ['Jo Koy','Stephan Lynch', 'Charlie Murphy', 'Michael'];
[Bindable] private var mems_of_A :ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(memA_array);

private var memB:Array = ['Ali','Ikram'];
[Bindable] private var mems_of_B:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(memB_array);         

private function divDataGridChange():void{
  if (divDataGrid.selectedIndex==0)
    memDataGrid.dataProvider=mems_of_A;
  else (divDataGrid.selectedIndex==1)
    memDataGrid.dataProvider=mems_of_B;
}

private function getCombinedUserNameLabel(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String
{
    return item.firstName + " " + item.lastName;
}

<mx:DataGrid id="divDataGrid" dataProvider="{divisions}" width="150" height="265" change="{divDataGridChange()}" selectedIndex="0">
  <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn width="150" headerText="Select a Division" />
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
<mx:DataGrid id="memDataGrid" dataProvider="{mems_of_A}" change="{monDataGridChange()}" selectedIndex="0">
  <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn width="150" headerText="Select a User" labelFunction="{getCombinedUserNameLabel}" />
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take care to your conditionals statements.

```
private function divDataGridChange():void{
  if (divDataGrid.selectedIndex==0)
    memDataGrid.dataProvider=mems_of_A;
  else (divDataGrid.selectedIndex==1)
    memDataGrid.dataProvider=mems_of_B;
}
```

should be

```
private function divDataGridChange():void{
  if (divDataGrid.selectedIndex==0)
    memDataGrid.dataProvider=mems_of_A;
  else if (divDataGrid.selectedIndex==1)
    memDataGrid.dataProvider=mems_of_B;
}
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_15.html

Comment: Oh. Thankyou. But the problem is still there i.e. Members' datagrid items don't change on clicking Divisions' datagrid items. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the method divDataGridChange() : `memDataGrid.invalidateDisplayList();`

Updated method :

```
private function divDataGridChange():void{
            if (divDataGrid.selectedIndex==0)
                memDataGrid.dataProvider=mems_of_A;
            else if (divDataGrid.selectedIndex==1)
                memDataGrid.dataProvider=mems_of_B;

            memDataGrid.invalidateDisplayList();
        }
```

Also replace the event from "**change**" to "**itemclick**".The divisions datagrid tag will be

```
<mx:DataGrid id="divDataGrid" dataProvider="{divisions}" width="150" height="265" itemClick="{divDataGridChange()}" selectedIndex="0" >
```